# Ionic 3 cordova running into device/emulator Error [Android]

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ionic3

I have causing an issue on running my ionic v3 cordova project to my physical device with this command.

Edit:

```
ionic cordova run android -l
```

Error Log:

**Fatal process OOM in heap setup**

[ERROR] Exception:

> Feel free to ask additional info if you have hint on fixing the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Can you try this command: `ionic cordova run android --prod`

Comment: It also fails. FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Answer (score 0):

You need to request more heap size by setting `android:largeHeap="true"` in the manifest.